# Can an arbitrary probability space be simulated by coin tosses?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $B=\left(\{\mathrm{heads},\mathrm{tails}\},\mathcal{P}\{\mathrm{heads},\mathrm{tails}\},\mu\right)$ be the probability space for a single fair coin toss. For any set $S$ let $B^S$ be the independent product probability space, representing an independent fair coin toss for each element of $S$.

For each probability space $A$, is there some set $S$ such that there exists a measure-preserving measurable function $B^S\rightarrow A$?

Comment: I sort of doubt that any continuous parameter stochastic processes could be modeled that way.

Comment: It is so if $X$ is a Borel space with cardinal being countable (cf. Kallenberg, chapter 3), which covers most interesting cases, for instance, every Polish space will do. Dunno about the general case.

Comment: @zoli You can certainally model the "sample continuous" stochastic processes with countably many coinflips, and indeed this is precisely how computers are able to simulate them.

Comment: I'm thinking about the Dieudonné measure on $\omega_1$.  It's not a very interesting space for probability, since every event has probability 0 or 1, but still I don't see how to get it as a pushforward of a coin flip measure.

Comment: Essentially, the answer to the question is yes by Maharam's structure theorem. However, the measurable functions given by this are isomorphisms of the measure algebra and not defined point wise on the underlying set.